# How should authenticated and unauthenticated components be handled in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am building an user interface for my Express API with React Redux and i wonder how to deal with authenticated and unauthenticated users. Is it a good idea to have two app components, one for authenticated and unauthenticated users - which will conditionally render inside the main component (app.js) if the JWT is successfully dispatched to redux state after user has logged in. Is this a good or bad approach for dealing with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's totally fine to create separate components fro authorized and unauthorized users. Why don't you just create a single component and pass the value as props and so you can handle it there in a single component?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using private and public routes in your main app component.

This [blog article](https://medium.com/@eymaslive/securing-react-redux-application-public-private-routes-337f0ab19b3) gives a good explanation.

with context-api your privateRoute.js could look something like this:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../../context/auth/authContext';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isAuthenticated, loading } = authContext;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
          <Redirect to='/login' />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

but you would have to query the AuthContext from your redux store.